# When increased desired count to 2 and update AWS ECS service through python script, it killing the existing task and creating 2 new tasks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I increased min and desired count to 2 and update AWS ECS service through python script, it killing the old task and creating 2 new tasks but my requirement is I need old task should be running and create 2nd task. But in my python script it killing the old task and creating 2 new tasks. please find below python and provide your inputs on this.

```
    **import boto3
import json
ECSCLUSTER = 'cluster_name'
SERVICEJSONFILENAME = 'services.json'
SERVICEJSONFILENAME_GENERATED = 'services-generated-pen.json'
ecsServiceClient = boto3.client('ecs')
autoScalingClient = boto3.client('application-autoscaling')
'''
Script can be used to update min,max and desried count for services in a ECS Cluster.
This script will update the values using data from a file in the same folder as this script ,services.json
The file can be initially generated by calling the method generate_service_file method, then updating the file for the desired values
And running the script with updateServices function..
'''
'''
generate_service_file -> Creates a service.json file for the given ECS Cluster, printing the current values of desired, min and max count per service
This file can be updated and used while running update service method to update the min , max and desired count for all services.
'''
def generate_service_file():
    services = []
    f = open(SERVICEJSONFILENAME_GENERATED, "w") #Overwrite Mode for File
    ecsServices = ecsServiceClient.list_services(cluster=ECSCLUSTER,maxResults=99)
    
    print('Get all services in cluster -'+ECSCLUSTER)
    for ecsServiceArn in ecsServices['serviceArns']:
        
        servicesToCheck = [ecsServiceArn]
        retServices = ecsServiceClient.describe_services(cluster = ECSCLUSTER, services=servicesToCheck)
        declaredService = retServices['services'][0]
        
        print ("Describing Service ----- "+retServices['services'][0]['serviceName'])
        srv  = EcsService()
        srv.name = retServices['services'][0]['serviceName']
        srv.desiredCount = retServices['services'][0]['desiredCount']
        scalingResponse = autoScalingClient.describe_scalable_targets(ServiceNamespace='ecs', ResourceIds=['service/'+ECSCLUSTER+'/'+declaredService['serviceName']])
        
        if len(scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'])>0:
            srv.minCount=scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['MinCapacity']
            srv.maxCount=scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['MaxCapacity']  
        else:
            print('    Scaling Policy Not configured - '+srv.name)
        services.append(srv)    
    json.dump(services,f,default=obj_dict,indent=4)     
    print('Created File '+SERVICEJSONFILENAME)
def updateServices():
    services = []
    fileInput = open(SERVICEJSONFILENAME,"r")
    servicesData = json.load(fileInput, object_hook=dict_to_obj)
    
    
    for s in servicesData:
        
        updateService = False    
        serviceToUpdate = EcsService()
        serviceToUpdate = s;
        
        retServices = ecsServiceClient.describe_services(cluster = ECSCLUSTER, services=[serviceToUpdate.name])
        if len(retServices['services']) <=0:
            print('Warning - Service Not in ECS Cluster - '+serviceToUpdate.name)
            continue
        else:
            print('Processing Changes for Service -'+serviceToUpdate.name)
        print('    Existing Desired Count - '+str(retServices['services'][0]['desiredCount']))
        if retServices['services'][0]['desiredCount'] != serviceToUpdate.desiredCount:
            print('    Desired Count will be updated to - '+str(serviceToUpdate.desiredCount))
            updateService = True
        
        scalingResponse = autoScalingClient.describe_scalable_targets(ServiceNamespace='ecs', ResourceIds=['service/'+ECSCLUSTER+'/'+serviceToUpdate.name])
        
        roleARN = ''
        ResourceId = ''
        ScalableDimension = ''
    
        if len(scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'])>0:
            print('    Existing Min Capacity and Max Capacity - '+str(scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['MinCapacity'])+','+str(scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['MaxCapacity']))
            if (scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['MinCapacity'] != serviceToUpdate.minCount) or (scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['MaxCapacity'] != serviceToUpdate.maxCount):
                 updateService = True
                 print('    Min and Max Capacity will be updated to - '+str(serviceToUpdate.minCount)+','+str(serviceToUpdate.maxCount))  
            roleARN = scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['RoleARN']
            ResourceId = scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['ResourceId']
            ScalableDimension = scalingResponse['ScalableTargets'][0]['ScalableDimension']
        else:
            print('    Warning - Scaling Policy Not configured - '+serviceToUpdate.name)
            continue
        if updateService==True:
            print('    Updating Service - '+serviceToUpdate.name)
            autoScalingClient.register_scalable_target(
                MaxCapacity=serviceToUpdate.maxCount,
                MinCapacity=serviceToUpdate.minCount,
                ResourceId=ResourceId,
                RoleARN=roleARN,
                ScalableDimension=ScalableDimension,
                ServiceNamespace='ecs'
                )
            ecsServiceClient.update_service(
                cluster=ECSCLUSTER,
                service=serviceToUpdate.name,
                forceNewDeployment=True)
            print('    Restarted Service - '+serviceToUpdate.name)
    
class EcsService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = '--none--'
        self.minCount = 1
        self.maxCount = 1
        self.desiredCount = 1
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
    def __eq__(self, other):
         return (
             self.__class__ == other.__class__ and
             self.name == other.name
         )    
        
        
def obj_dict(obj):
    return obj.__dict__
# Convert a dict object to a Teacher class instance.    
def dict_to_obj(dict):
    ret = EcsService()
    ret.name = dict['name']
    ret.minCount = dict['minCount']
    ret.maxCount = dict['maxCount']
    ret.desiredCount = dict['desiredCount']
    return ret
def safe_list_idx (listData, idxObject):
  try:
    return listData.index(idxObject)
  except ValueError:
    return -1
#generate_service_file()
updateServices()**
```

service.json file looks like below

[
{
"name": "service_name",
"minCount": 2,
"maxCount": 3,
"desiredCount": 2
}
]

Comment: whenever you update a task it will create a new one, catch is here do you want to refer same image or not? if so then i believe there should be no issue as same code is getting executed by new task.

Comment: we are referring to same image only and we tried same process manually from AWS console, increased min and desired count to 2 and verified it. From console it not killing the old task, the old task is remains same and creating 2nd task as new. So we need our python script to work as per AWS Console manual process.

Comment: are you also updating the ECS service with new task number? if so then AWS automatically rollover old one with new task definition.  and that's how ECS works. it's take some time to clean the old instance but eventually it's kill the old one once new instance is stable. BTW, you can also manually kill the old running instance through console(not recommended).

Comment: this issue is resolved by just making the forceNewDeployment=false.
Thank you so much for your time.